# elasticsearch.BadRequestError: BadRequestError(400, 'parsing_exception', 'unknown query [query]')

Tags: python, elasticsearch

The specific error traceback is as follows：

Here is my current Python code:

```
top_k=3
query = {
    "query": {
        "script_score": {
            "query": {
                "match_all": {}
            },
            "script": {
                "source": "cosineSimilarity(params.query_vector, 'ask_vector') + 1.0",
                "lang": "painless",
                "params": {
                    "query_vector": query_embedding.tolist()
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "size": top_k
}
res = es.search(index=index_name, query=query)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

try replace **query** to **body**.

> res = es.search(index=index_name, body=query)

Comment: If I replace query with body, I get the following error again：

elasticsearch.BadRequestError: BadRequestError(400, 'search_phase_execution_exception', 'runtime error')

Comment: It's been solved, it's the datatype that wasn't successfully defined as a vector